# Why do these queries yield different results in MySQL 5.5 vs 5.6?

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain why these two queries (one using `IN` and one using `EXISTS`) return different results in MySQL 5.6 but not in MySQL 5.5?

Using `EXPLAIN`, I can see different execution plans for each, but I need help understanding what's going on, and why would this `IN` logic be broken in 5.6 but not 5.5?

Fiddle illustrating the problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da52b/95

Members can have two addresses: a home address and a firm address.  The desired result is to provide a region X and get a list of all members with a mailing address in that region.  The mailing address is the firm address if it exists, otherwise it is the home address.  Cities can belong to one or more regions.

**Simplified database structure and data:**

```
CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `c_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `city`
VALUES
  ('1', 'Hillsdale'),
  ('2', 'Smallville'),
  ('3', 'Oakside'),
  ('4', 'Lakeview');

CREATE TABLE `city_region` (
  `cr_city` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cr_region` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cr_city`,`cr_region`)
);

INSERT INTO `city_region`
VALUES
  ('1', '3'),
  ('2', '1'),
  ('3', '1'),
  ('3', '2'),
  ('4', '1'),
  ('4', '3');

CREATE TABLE `firm_address` (
  `fa_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fa_member` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fa_city` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fa_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `firm_address`
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '3'),
  ('2', '2', '2'),
  ('3', '3', '1'),
  ('4', '6', '2'),
  ('5', '7', '1');

CREATE TABLE `home_address` (
  `ha_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ha_member` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ha_city` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ha_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `home_address`
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2'),
  ('2', '2', '3'),
  ('3', '3', '1'),
  ('4', '4', '1'),
  ('5', '5', '2'),
  ('6', '6', '2');

CREATE TABLE `member` (
  `m_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `m_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`m_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `member`
VALUES
  ('1', 'John'),
  ('2', 'Bob'),
  ('3', 'Dave'),
  ('4', 'Jane'),
  ('5', 'Mary'),
  ('6', 'Karen'),
  ('7', 'Christie');

CREATE TABLE `region` (
  `r_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `r_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`r_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `region`
VALUES
  ('1', 'Central'),
  ('2', 'Lake District'),
  ('3', 'Westside');
```

**Query 1 (wrong, missing a member):**

```
SELECT * FROM member

LEFT OUTER JOIN home_address ON m_id = ha_member
LEFT OUTER JOIN city home_city ON ha_city = home_city.c_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN firm_address ON m_id = fa_member
LEFT OUTER JOIN city firm_city ON fa_city = firm_city.c_id

WHERE 1 IN (
    SELECT r_id
    FROM region
    INNER JOIN city_region ON r_id = cr_region
    WHERE cr_city = IF(fa_city IS NULL, ha_city, fa_city)
)
```

**Query 2 (returning the correct results):**

```
SELECT * FROM member

LEFT OUTER JOIN home_address ON m_id = ha_member
LEFT OUTER JOIN city home_city ON ha_city = home_city.c_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN firm_address ON m_id = fa_member
LEFT OUTER JOIN city firm_city ON fa_city = firm_city.c_id

WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT r_id
    FROM region
    INNER JOIN city_region ON r_id = cr_region
    WHERE cr_city = IF(fa_city IS NULL, ha_city, fa_city)
    AND r_id = 1
)
```

Any help understanding this inconsistency would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is `r_id` ever null in the subquery oin the WHERE clause?

Comment: Please edit your query to have table aliases.  It is impossible to tell where the columns are coming from.

Comment: These two queries give identic results, please take a look at this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/102218/3

Comment: The results are identical in v5.5 but not 5.6, updated question to clarify this. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: So, there is no question here?

Comment: Question is sentence 1 and 2

Comment: I think it has more to do with `IF()` function than with `IN` operator. I've changed `WHERE cr_city = IF(fa_city IS NULL, ha_city, fa_city)` to `WHERE cr_city = IFNULL(fa_city, ha_city)` it started to work in both versions. You should also check if it is working in newest version of MYSQL 5.6 (5.6.15 at the moment and on sqlfiddle there is 5.6.6)

Comment: The comparison linking the subselect to the main query is different: query 1 compares 1 to `r_id`, while query 2 compares `cr_region` to 1. There are different columns!

Comment: The cr_region is just an inconsistency in my example, those columns are INNER JOIN in that subquery so r_id = cr_region.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I spent some time looking at this today, and it appears to be a bug in MySQL 5.6. (I also tested MySQL 5.6.15 and got the same result.)

MySQL 5.6 uses some new optimizations in executing this query, but they do not seem to be responsible for the difference, as it does not help to set e.g.:

```
set session optimizer_switch="block_nested_loop=off";
```

Using `IFNULL(fa_city, ha_city)` instead of `IF(fa_city IS NULL, ha_city, fa_city)` does yield a correct result, so the bug appears to be somewhere in the processing of `IF()`.

Comment: Jeremy. Thanks for looking at this. I will file a ticket with mysql and award bounty when the waiting period is up

Comment: Did you create bug ticket in http://bugs.mysql.com/ if so, could I see URL to it?